# IIS 8 FTP Service is ignoring defined port range

Tags: iis, ftp, port

I'm having trouble setting up an FTP server in Windows Server 2012, using IIS 8.
This should be fairly straightforward but I'm struggling with convincing IIS to use a port range that I've specified.

In IIS, under FTP Firewall Support, the range I've selected is 41000-42000. Our external IP is listed and if I forward all traffic from our firewall, this works fine. The problem is, when I forward just ports 20, 21 and 41000-42000, it doesn't establish a passive connection. This is the log from Filezilla (IP Masked):

```
    Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xx,xxx,148,250)
    Command:    LIST
    Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
    Error:  Connection timed out
    Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Now I believe that the server is suggesting that we use port 38138, based on 148*256 + 250, which is outside of the defined range of 41000-42000. This would explain why it's failing to connect.
I've googled around and this is quite a common issue, but the solution is to restart the Microsoft FTP service. Unfortunately, I have tried this and it has made no difference. I've also restarted IIS and even the whole server but it's still throwing out an incorrect port range. I cannot find anything specific to IIS 8 regarding this, nor can I find anyone else who has the same issue but restarting the service hasn't fixed.

Has anyone got any ideas? Is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to figure out the cause of this, at least why the wrong ports are being sent.

I gave up on Microsoft's FTP server and decided to use Filezilla instead but to my surprise it had the exact same issue. However, from viewing the logs Filezilla provides, I observed that it was actually requesting the correct ports but by the time the packets got to the client, the port range had been modified.

This, I believe, happens with some firewalls or routers. At least I'm confident Microsoft's FTP service was actually doing it's job now and I can continue this investigation

Answer (score 2):

In IIS....

1. Click the servername
2. CLick on FTP Firewall Support
3. Set these to your liking...

Then...

4. You must iisreset

This issue drove me mad, since nothing tells you this.  I finally found someone on a old MS board who just said IIS reset... Did and it works great. :)

Comment: Not iisreset. You have to restart ftpsvc ("Microsoft FTP Server") instead!

Comment: Mike, thank you!  After much searching, I found this is the reason why my PASV connection wasn't picking up the ports I had designated.

Comment: Mike's comment solved it for me. iisreset just wasn't enough.